# How to count number of occurrences of more than one elements in a list using Java 8 Stream or collections framework

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

If we have an ArrayList in Java, as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
animals.add("bat");
animals.add("bat");
animals.add("owl");
animals.add("bat");
animals.add("parrot");
animals.add("owl");
animals.add("owl");
animals.add("bat");
```

How can we get count of **only** `"bat"` and `"owl"` from this list using Java 8 Stream API / Collections in single iteration?

Comment: try out something, hint: look for how you can groupBy and count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Set<String> itemToFilter = Stream.of("bat", "owl")
                                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

    Map<String, Long> result = animals.stream()
                                    .filter(animal  -> itemToFilter.contains(animal))
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(animal -> animal , Collectors.counting()));

    System.out.println("result ="+ result);
```

Comment: `List.of("bat", "owl").contains(animal)` can be a cleaner approach and will allow room for expansion in the future with an ease.

Comment: one would generally prefer a `Set` to perform `contains` for performance benefits.

Comment: @Naman Yeah good point. I was wondering if defining a set outside lambda (since it is non changing computation) would benefit in terms of performance?

Comment: You don’t need to insist on a `HashSet`, `Collectors.toSet()` is sufficient. Further, there’s no sense in `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(…))` when all you want is `count()`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Map<String, Long> collect = animals.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: but this will be returning count of all the animals in the map, what if we have huge list of list elements, and we don't want all elements in map, but just the 2 mentioned in question?

Comment: Use .filter(a -> a.equals("bat") || a.equals("owl")).collect(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy and count in Stream API.

```
Map<String, Long> counts = animals.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: but this will be returning count of all the animals in the map, what if we have huge list of list elements, and we don't want all elements in map, but just the 2 mentioned in question?

Comment: Please try to avoid duplicate answers :)